# Google Collaboratory Downloaded Libraries and Files Location

Tags: python, ipython

So, when using Google Collab, by default it's actually a built-in Python environment in the browser, right? Usually, user will import library from Unknown location into Collab.

I said Unknown location because I didn't know where all these libraries are stored. Let say, I'm downloading new library such as Numpy with `!pip install numpy`, and of course can be checked by invoking `!pip list`.

So, where does all this libraries are installed? I checked on my Drive and I can only found the .ipynb files, not the libraries.

Comment: Try asking the question on StackOverflow.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal i thought i already on the correct platform

Comment: There is a Google virtual machine with a great amount of Ram. You can view how many ram and cpu are you using in a top right icon.

Comment: @malcubierre i know that one. So it's download to that location? How can I access it?